# Laplace transform of a rectangle function

Tags: symbolic

I defined a rectangle function as below:

```
rect[t_, T_] := (Sign[t] - Sign[t - T])/2
```

The laplace transform should be

$$
\frac{1-e^{-sT}}{s}
$$

But the code below in Mathematica won't work:

```
LaplaceTransform[rect[t, T], t, s] // Simplify
```

It just throw out the answer below after some long time:

```
1/2 (1/s - LaplaceTransform[Sign[t - T], t, s])
```

I think the problem comes from the factor 'T', because it can handle `rect[t,1]` or `rect[t,10]`..., well.

Then how to do the laplace transformation of this function `rect[t, T]` with 'T' given as a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workaround:

```
rect[t_, T_] := Sign[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - T];(*Or:Sign[t] - UnitStep[t - T]*)
FullSimplify[LaplaceTransform[rect[t, T], t, s], Assumptions -> T > 0]
(* (1 - E^(-s T))/s  *)
```

**Edited:**

```
rect[t_, T_] := (Sign[t] - Sign[t - T])/2;
Assuming[T > 0, LaplaceTransform[rect[t, T], t, s]] // Simplify
(* (1 - E^(-s T))/s  *)
```